# SQL INSERT INTO with SELECT statement and INNER JOIN with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this query for insert data from one table to another with the following condition hours on table field `CHECKTIME >= 12` should be insert into `Att_process` table, This query executing successfully on SQL Server but data doesn't insert in to the table, but hours > 12 data also in the table

```
INSERT INTO Att_process(USERID,checkout_time)
    SELECT 
        CHECKINOUT.USERID, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
    FROM
        CHECKINOUT 
    INNER JOIN 
        Att_process ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = Att_process.USERID
    WHERE
        DATEPART(HOUR, CHECKTIME) >= 12;
```

[image]

Can any one help me on this really appreciated

Comment: Did u check the result after inner join with Att_process ?

Comment: If you execute the SELECT part alone (without doing insert), is the result as expected?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the where clause, as people above have mentioned I suspect it is to do with the join.

Comment: Why do you need the join in the first place?

Comment: Hi jarlh,i got the result only from select part

Comment: guys this query successfully executed on sql,but it says 0 rows affected,as you can seen on image of the the particular table there are values more than 12

Comment: TSungur,i used inner join becase i have to insert data into Attendance process  tables that's why  TSungur

Comment: if i execute query like this its displaying result    SELECT * from CHECKINOUT where DATEPART(HOUR, CHECKTIME) >= 12

Answer (score 1):

Is there already data in your Att_process table ?

You are joining with User_ID of Att_process table at the same time trying to insert in the table you are joining. So how join will produce data?

Please let us know about Att_process table and its relation with CHECKINOUT table.

probably what you may need is

```
INSERT INTO Att_process(USERID,checkout_time)
    (SELECT 
        CHECKINOUT.USERID, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
    FROM
        CHECKINOUT         
    WHERE
        DATEPART(HOUR, CHECKTIME) >= 12;
    )
```

Comment: Attn_process table have Three fields USERID, checkin_time, checkout_time so i need to check if time value more than 12 ,those values should insert to Att_process table filed checkout_time,USERID and CHECKTIME is the primary key of CHECKINOUT  table

Comment: There are no record on Attn_process table

Comment: if i run this query it will shows data SELECT * from CHECKINOUT where DATEPART(HOUR, CHECKTIME) >= 12

Comment: @KanjulaKumara: If there are no record in the Attn_processs, you can't apply join dear. Remove the join and try as in my answer and see if that is what you need.

Comment: @KanjulaKumara: If it helped you, you may accept the answer and/or upvote :-)

Comment: How do i Do it here i am New to stack over flow

Comment: @KanjulaKumara: You get a small Green tick-mark besides votes of the answer which you have to click to "accept" answer. To upvote, you need to click small grey up arrow and to downvote, small grey downwards arrow. Hope that helps.